# Let $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \in V$ be such that $\left\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\right\}$ is a linearly dependent set...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Q. Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4} \in V$ be such that $\left\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\right\}$ is a linearly dependent set but $\left\{v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4}\right\}$ is a linearly independent set. Prove that: $v_{1}$ is a linear combination of $v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$

I've attached an image showing a *Possible Solution*:-
[image]

What I'm failing to understand is how does the linear independence of $\left\{v_{4}, v_{2}, v_{3}\right\}$ and it's corresponding coefficients (all of which are equal to $0$) have any impact on the linear dependence of $\left\{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\right\}$ given that they are 2 different sets with a common vector space?

Here, it seems to imply that with the linear dependence of $\left\{v_{4}, v_{2}, v_{3}\right\}$, given any set containing $v_2$, the coefficient of $v_2=0$. Given the concept of linear independence, I suspect this to be wrong, but I'm not sure?

Comment: You are given the information that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ are linearly dependent.  This fact does not follow from the linear independence of $\{v_2, v_3, v_4\}$.  It's part of the hypothesis of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is correct. $\{v_4,v_3,v_2\}$ linearly independet implies that $\{v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent as well (the reason is well explained in the text and this is a general resoult; If $S$ is a set of linearly indepent vectors every subset of $S$ is linearly independent)

Your goal is to stablish that $\alpha_1\neq 0$ but it is inmediatly because if $\alpha_1= 0$ then your have a combination
$\alpha_2 v_2 +\alpha_3 v_3=0$ where at least one $\alpha_i \neq 0$ (Follow by your initial hypothesis) but this implies that
$\{v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly dependent and this is a contradiction.

Hope this helps you.